# Page Worker - destroy() does not seems to remove the window object

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a SDK add-on that creates a page worker

```
events.on(eventTarget, "sandbox", (details, content) => {
  var pageWorker = worker.Page({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("sandbox.js"),
    contentURL: data.url("sandbox.html"),
    contentScriptWhen: "end"
  });

  pageWorker.port.emit("detect-version", content, funcs);

  pageWorker.port.on("version-detected", (result) => {
    if (result.version) {
      events.emit(eventTarget, "result-ready", details, results);
    }
  });
  pageWorker.port.on("done", () => {
    pageWorker.destroy();
  });
});
```

As you see on the sandbox event there are some messaging back and forth between the add-on and the page worker

- the page worker is created
- sends a message: detect-version
- listens for version-detected
- listens for the done event, calls destroy() on the page worker

I expect the `worker.destroy()` to remove the object and the background page etc.
This does not seem to happen. If I do a browser session for an hour the browser's memory usage is very high and if I check `about:memory` in Firefox I see a lot of `sandbox.html` windows entries which I guess indicates that they are not destroyed.

Does anyone know if this is a bug in 1.14? 
or am I doing something wrong here? Other options? I need to have a sandboxed page that can communicate with the add-on and pageworker seems to be the only choice for now.

I see there was a bug fix commited 2013-09-26 in the SDK repo that could relate to this https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/commit/55aeedc69984a2c0df78ddb17cee35a960b1135b

Thank you in advance for any help on this
t.

Comment: Might be a bug. Hard to tell, without a full, self-contained example reproducing the problem, so give one please. The commit you listed could indeed be a bugfix for exactly this. Please note that these days add-ons will not use the modules/module versions that come with the SDK, but those shipped within Firefox itself.

Comment: thanks nmaier. The mentioned bug fix did not solve this one. I filed a bug for this here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934296

Comment: Is this resolved or it still remains as a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This still seems to be an issue and I doubt there will be a fix for it. I just came across this and ended up minimizing the side effects by just loading a small static resource at the end of my script:

```js
window.location = "data:text/plain,goodbye";
```

This way any repeating background requests on the original page will no longer run. Be aware though that this will cause the page worker script to re-evaluate, so you are going to have to check `window.location` at the top of your script.